# How to Use Cypress and Gherkin to automate one scenario with four different users using fixture?

Tags: javascript, cypress, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress and Gherking but I have some scenarios where I have to execute it with more than one user.

I don't want to use the Scenario Outline for it because I would have to create a table for each scenario. My user data are at a fixture file, but I don't know how to execute for each user the scenarios.

Is there a way to set the user and execute the scenario once, but for all the 4 users?

My fixture file:

```
{   
  "standard":{  
      "name": "The site should work as expected for this user",
      "user_name": "standard_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },

    "locked":{  
      "name": "User is locked out and should not be able to log in.",
      "user_name": "locked_out_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },

    "problem":{  
      "name": "Images are not loading for this user.",
      "user_name": "problem_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },

    "performance":{  
      "name": "This user has high loading times. Does the site still work as expected?",
      "user_name": "performance_glitch_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    }
}
```

ShopList.feature example:

```
 Scenario: Validate Add to cart counter for each user
        Given the user log in into the application
        When he adds products to the cart
        Then the amount added should be the same as the counter
        And the cart should contains the added itens
```

I found a solution using .foreach() but for the it() function

```
users.forEach((user) => {
  it(`Log in with ${user.username}`, () => {
    // Visit the login page and enter login credentials for each user
    cy.visit('/login');
    cy.get('#username').type(user.username);
    cy.get('#password').type(user.password);
    cy.get('#login-button').click();
```

I want the same result but integrating it with gherkin.